# What the difference between cm:content and sys:base

Tags: alfresco

I create a new content model, and i made its inheritance to be associated with `cm:content` to save the nodes as content under specific folder.

But, What if i want to associate the content model with `sys:base` as example ? Where the nodes will be saved ? How to create a container for the nodes ?

Person and other content does not inherit from `cm:content`, and i don't want the user to manage the nodes from something else where, i want to ensure that the user will manage the nodes created from the new content model from created dialogs and pages designed to serve something like this.

all of your replies is highly appreciated

Mohammed Amr
Senior System Developer
Digital Series Co.

Answer (score 6):

`sys:base` is defined in [`systemModel.xml`](http://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/repository/config/alfresco/model/systemModel.xml) as follows (last HEAD revision showed here):

```
  <type name="sys:base">
     <title>Base</title>
     <mandatory-aspects>
        <aspect>sys:referenceable</aspect>
        <aspect>sys:localized</aspect>
     </mandatory-aspects>
  </type>
```

Go through the `systemModel` to learn about the two aspects that are mandatory for such type. `cm:content` inherits indirectly from `sys:base`, as you can see in the [`contentModel.xml`](http://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/repository/config/alfresco/model/contentModel.xml), passing through `cm:object` that puts some constraints and indexing fairy powder onto it.

In the `contentModel`, you can also see that `cm:folder` exposes a new association named `cm:contains` that target `sys:base` objects. This means that within a `cm:folder` (and subtypes) you can store every type in the hierarchy branch started by `sys:base`, including `cm:object` and `cm:content`.

This should be already enough to show you how:

- to create containers that allow for specific child types
- there's no big difference between `cm:content` and `sys:base` when it comes to storing such types in a `cm:folder`
- types are in a inheritance hierarchy, and as such you choose which type to inherit from depending on its properties and relationships with other entities in the repository
- if you want, you could inherit from `sys:base` instead of `cm:content` or `cm:object`, but then you'll miss all of the features introduced by those more high level types

I can't see why content types should change or affect the way users access content, especially if you have your own pages to show content to users.

As a side note, also `usr:user` inherits from `sys:base`, as you can see in the [`userModel.xml`](http://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/repository/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/security/authentication/userModel.xml)

Comment: if the content inherited from the cm:content the nodes created will be seen in the folder and the user have an access can delete them or make a change on their properties. So i need to make them inherited from sys:base to be unseen and enforce the user to walk through the designed pages from maintain process. What are you think ?

Comment: I think you're getting security wrong here: don't rely on content types to enforce security contrains such as make content not visible or not accessible, as you might have some different UI behave differntly. I would rather set permissions on content so that normal users can't do anything (e.g. `Consumer` role, or `No Privileges`), and have some logic that runs with more privileges allowing managing content.